# std::thread wrapper with run method

Tags: c++11, gcc, c++14

I am trying to write a wrapper for std::thread with a run method , which will allow thread to execute only once run is called.

```
       class ThreadRAII_WITHRUN {                                                                                                                                                 

public:                                                                                                                                                                    
enum class DtorAction { join, detach };                                                                                                                                

template< class Function, class... Args >                                                                                                                              
ThreadRAII_WITHRUN(DtorAction a,Function&& f, Args&&... args)                                                                                                          
: action(a)                                                                                                                                                            
, t(std::thread([&](){pro.get_future().wait(); std::forward<Function>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}))                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                      

void run()                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                      
    pro.set_value();                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                      

~ThreadRAII_WITHRUN()                                                                                                                                                  
{                                                                                                                                                                      
if (t.joinable()) { // joinability test                                                                                                                                
    if (action == DtorAction::join) {                                                                                                                                  
    t.join();                                                                                                                                                          
    } else {                                                                                                                                                           
    t.detach();                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                      
ThreadRAII_WITHRUN(ThreadRAII_WITHRUN&&) = default; // support                                                                                                         
ThreadRAII_WITHRUN& operator=(ThreadRAII_WITHRUN&&) = default; // moving                                                                                               
std::thread& get() { return t; }                                                                                                                           

private: // as before                                                                                                                                                      
DtorAction action;                                                                                                                                                     
std::promise<void> pro;                                                                                                                                                
std::thread t;                                                                                                                                                         

};
```

This code compiles with gcc6.1.0 but not with gcc4.8.5

with gcc4.8.5 with -std=c++11 flag I get below error.

```
g++ -std=c++11 thread.cpp -pthread
thread.cpp: In lambda function:
thread.cpp:74:94: error: parameter packs not expanded with â...â:
  , t(std::thread([&](){pro.get_future().wait(); std::forward<Function>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}))
                                                                                              ^
thread.cpp:74:94: note:         âargsâ
thread.cpp: In instantiation of âstruct ThreadRAII_WITHRUN::ThreadRAII_WITHRUN(ThreadRAII_WITHRUN::DtorAction, Function&&, Args&& ...) [with Function = threadwithraii_run()::__lambda10; Args = {int}]::__lambda9â:
thread.cpp:74:106:   required from âThreadRAII_WITHRUN::ThreadRAII_WITHRUN(ThreadRAII_WITHRUN::DtorAction, Function&&, Args&& ...) [with Function = threadwithraii_run()::__lambda10; Args = {int}]â
thread.cpp:104:117:   required from here
thread.cpp:74:94: error: using invalid field âThreadRAII_WITHRUN::ThreadRAII_WITHRUN(ThreadRAII_WITHRUN::DtorAction, Function&&, Args&& ...)::__lambda9::__argsâ
```

does anyboday know the reason for the same?

Comment: GCC 4.8 barely supports C++11, much less C++14. You also need to add `-std=c++0x` when building with GCC 4.8 to enable the C++11 features it does support.

Comment: edited the question with error message , I do provide -std=c++11 flag with gcc4.8.5

Answer (score 0):

A bit off-topic, that lambda captures constructor arguments by references. By the time `run` is called some or all of these references may have become invalid. Capturing arguments by value may be safer, e.g.:

```
std::thread([=](){ ... })) 
             ^
             |
             capture by value
```

Comment: Thanks for that.But once parameter pack is captured as value it again need to be passed to function as value and can't be perfect forwarded :( 
  <br/>  


   t(std::thread([=](){pro.get_future().wait(); f(args...);}))

Comment: @user8063157 Well, you can have safety or perfect forwarding here, pick one.